# Save xlsx file to disk in Sidekiq as background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, axlsx

I am trying to generate excel file in background by using axlsx and save it (Rails4.2). In GitHub page of [axlsx](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails), it says `As of Rails 4.1 you must use render_to_string to render a mail attachment`. However, it throws me a error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'render_to_string' for #<CreateExcelSheetWorker:0x007fbccf51db30>`

My worker class:

```
class CreateExcelSheetWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  recurrence { daily }

  def perform()
    model = SomeModel.where(wanted: true).order(started_at: :desc)
    xlsx = render_to_string handlers: [:axlsx], formats: [:xlsx], template: "template/file", locals: {model: model}
    path = "/tmp/a.xlsx"
    File.open(path, "w+") do |f|
      f.write(xlsx)
    end
  end
end
```

I cannot figure out how to fix this, any help appreciated.

Comment: The page you linked is for `axlsx_rails`, not `axlsx`, those are different gems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `render_to_string` comment is for usage of the gem in actionmailers. Outside of any kind of view context, you'll have to use xlsx builder api directly. Something like this:

```
package = Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  p.workbook.add_worksheet(name: "Summary") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["foo", 1]
  end
end

File.write(filename, package.to_stream.read)
```

Comment: thanks! I wonder Is there any way to use xlsx template file like in axlsx_rails?

Answer (score 1):

Sergio's answer is fine. But, if you are wanting to use the axlsx_rails template, you can use this example, which builds a fake view context to render the template:

```
require 'abstract_controller'
require 'action_controller'
require 'action_view'
require 'active_record'

# require any helpers
require './app/helpers/application_helper'

# active record only if data is here
require './app/models/widget'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'sqlite3',
  database: 'db/development.sqlite3'
)

ActionController::Base.prepend_view_path "./app/views/"
# place data in view_assigns
view_assigns = {widgets: Widget.all}
av = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, view_assigns)
av.class_eval do
  # include any needed helpers (for the view)
  include ApplicationHelper
end

# normal render statement
content = av.render template: 'widgets/index.xlsx.axlsx'
# do something with content, such as:
File.open("/tmp/with_runner.xlsx","w+b") {|f| f.puts content }
```

https://gist.github.com/straydogstudio/dceb775ead81470cea70

Comment: But that template, it simply contains the same kind of code (add_worksheet, add_row, etc.) Why create a template and fake view context at all, when you can just extract a method, for example. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, post code in the answer directly. External links go dead.

Comment: If you already have your code in templates using axlsx_rails, then the above code is a way to keep it that way. There is nothing to prevent you from refactoring and using common functions.